# Supervising hardware installation when traveling to the US using VWP

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, work

I fly to Florida on Tuesday for a fortnights holiday and have been asked by my employer to return 6 days after I return to supervise installation of video walls supplied by a UK company sold to an American company and fitted Into shopping malls across America. This will be for 3-4 weeks depending on progress.

American labor will be used to install but for warranty we have to supervise correct installation as these are big units. We.do this all over the world my last trip was to Qatar for them and was exactly the same deal we supervised installation.

I am British myself and already have an ESTA for the holiday will this suffice for the work and would I need to notify them I am returning?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90485/can-i-fit-a-kitchen-in-the-us-on-the-visa-waiver-program

Comment: *If* your work is allowed as a business visitor, then you can use your existing ESTA for your second trip (assuming it doesn't expire in the meanwhile; they're normally good for two years).  It sounds to me like your trip is allowed as a business visitor but I am not an expert in such matters so I will leave it to someone else to answer.

Comment: @SheikPaul [The business visa flyer](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) specifically mentions supervision by a "service engineer" as an allowed business purpose. This is a question that is essentially calling for legal advice, and I'm not providing it, but clearly DOS has different definitions than you.

Comment: @ZachLipton The flyer clarifies things very nicely.

Comment: Ha @ZachLipton and I got to the flier at the same time :)

Answer (score 4):

Nobody needs to be notified and if I am reading the [business visa flier](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) correctly then this is totally allowed:

> Engineer(s) install, service or repair commercial or industrial equipment
>   or machinery sold by a non-U.S. company to a U.S. buyer, when
>   specifically required by the purchase contract. Installation cannot
>   include construction work, except for supervision or training of U.S.
>   workers to perform construction.

you said "supplied by a UK company sold to an American company" and "supervise". Now, supervision is allowed even for construction not to mention "commerical equipment".

Make sure you have the contract saying supervision is required and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for all the info giys. I'd read that flyer but not 100% sure I was allowed. Makes life a lot easier.